# Is it possible to retrieve gif attached to a tweet?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm searching tweets through Twitter API with [this endpoint](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json)

I'm testing with my own account. I tweeted a gif. 
But when I retrieve the json, I don't see the link of the attached media.
It's automatically format in an url.

My aim is to store locally the images attached to tweets.

Comment: file_get_contents on the url to the gif and you are golden

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to know if it's a gif or not? The url might not leads to a gif.

Comment: not reliably without downloading it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  If you are looking for animated GIFs, you need to look in the `extended_entities` - here's an example:

`"extended_entities": {
    "media": [
      {
        "id": 626705406224658400,
        "id_str": "626705406224658432",
        "indices": [
          29,
          51
        ],
        "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CLKBPxzWcAAFhYz.png",
        "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video_thumb/CLKBPxzWcAAFhYz.png",
        "url": "http://t.co/psSAzQfcFu",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/psSAzQfcFu",
        "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/edent/status/626705407550078976/photo/1",
        "type": "animated_gif",`

**See!** It tells you that there is an aGIF.  Later on, you'll see the URL to directly download it.

`"sizes": {
          "small": {
            "w": 14,
            "h": 14,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "medium": {
            "w": 14,
            "h": 14,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "thumb": {
            "w": 14,
            "h": 14,
            "resize": "crop"
          },
          "large": {
            "w": 14,
            "h": 14,
            "resize": "fit"
          }
        },
        "video_info": {
          "aspect_ratio": [
            1,
            1
          ],
          "variants": [
            {
              "bitrate": 0,
              "content_type": "video/mp4",
              "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/CLKBPxzWcAAFhYz.mp4"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },`

Now, you can't download the GIF directly, but you can grab the video version of it.

If you want other imgage (JPG, PNG, etc) take a look for the `"media_url_https"` field.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for you answer! I'm using the endpoint search/tweets but the extended_entities are not return with this method. Do I have to query for each tweet returned by the research?

Comment: Yes. But you can use https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup to get up to 100 Tweet objects at once.